# PHP logical operator

Tags: php, session, if-statement, logical-operators

When the `isset()` is executed the following check `$_SESSION['mat'] == "1"` is executed or the second verification is directly skipped since it is the first false?

Is there is where I have the doubt?

```
if(isset($_SESSION['mat']) and $_SESSION['mat']=="1"){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first part of your if statement already returns `false` the second part will not be evaluated. Your if statement looks good this way and shouldn't throw any index out of bounds errors.

Answer (score 0):

> When the isset is executed the following check is executed ($ _ SESSION ['mat'] == "1") or the second verification is directly skipped since it is the first false.

`isset()` will check if a variable is set otherwise it will return false. All the code inside the `if()` statement will be executed, so in your case, if the `$_SESSION` array variable isn't set, the second control, in your case `and` (that can be expressed also using &&) will be skipped.